# Regex to match specific number

Tags: python, regex

I currently have the regex `"(?<!mp){i}"` which matches a specific number but it overmatches and includes `10`, `11`, `21`, `etc` when I want to match `1`. In  short, it is matching as long as `i` contains the number in the string (if `i=2` and the string contains "xxxxxx 24" it would also match, which I don't want)

strings

```
xx 1.mp4
xx 10.mp4
xx21.mp4
xx1.mp4
xx 1 xx.mp4
xx.1.xxx.mp4
xx.11.xxx.mp4
xxx s1e3 xxx.mp4
xxx season 1 episode 3
xxx season 2 episode 1
```

expected outcome if trying to match where `i=1`

```
xx 1.mp4
xx1.mp4
xx 1 xx.mp4
xx.1.xxx.mp4
xxx season 2 episode 1
```

note: `xxx s1e3 xxx.mp4` and `xxx season 1 episode 3` was NOT match even though it contains `1` because it was followed by `s` and `season`. However, `xxx season 2 episode 1` Should be match, since the "episode" contains `1`

Another note: Ideally, it shouldn't be limited to just 1, since I wouldn't want to match `24` `32` when I am trying to find a match for `i=2`, etc

I've tried

```
if re.search(rf"(?<!mp){i}", string):
                do something
```

it returns strings with `10`,`11`, `21` `100`, etc when I am just searching for `1`. Likewise with `i=2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use negative lookaheads and lookbehinds to ensure that the number is not adjacent to any other digits.

```py
if re.search(rf"(?<!\d){i}(?!\d)", string):
```